# How to add string into passed arguments in vbs

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have passed arguments from [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), I am trying to add string into passed arguments but I am getting

> ```
> VBScript runtime error: Object required: '(string : "Wscript.Arguments(0)"
> ```

Below are the code snippets:

Batch file:

```
cscript VB.vbs %currentWorkingDir%
```

VB script file:

```
Const FileIn = Wscript.Arguments(0) + \FolderName\FileName
```

If I am using `Wscript.Echo Wscript.Arguments(0)` I am able to see the proper path but I am not able to concatenate two strings, please let me know how to do it, I am very new to `.vbs` and batch scripting.

Comment: Here Is My Way : `File = WSH.Arguments(0) & "\Folder-Here"`

Answer (score 0):

- Use `&` to concatenate strings rather than `+` (The latter works but can cause type coercion issues)
- "Double quote string literals"
- You use `Const` but `Wscript.Arguments(0)` is not a constant value - its determined at runtime

Change to:

```
dim FileIn
FileIn = Wscript.Arguments(0) & "\FolderName\FileName"
```

Comment: @Harsh, if this works for you and fully solves your problem, please consider to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer!